# Not able to create Sqlite database in Cordova

Tags: android, jquery, database, sqlite, cordova

I am trying to create a Sqlite Database and subsequently a table with one column and insert , Read the Values from it .I have added sqlite plugin for Cordova from CLI and i can see it as `com.brodysoft.sqlitePlugin` under the plugins section.Now on `onDeviceReady` i am trying to create the database..Here is the Code..

```
function onDeviceReady() {

 var databaseName =  "techDB";
 var databaseVersion = "1.0";
 var databaseDisplayName = "TTDatabase";
 var databaseSize =  25;
 var myDB = "";

 //Accessing with HTML5 local database
 myDB = window.openDatabase(databaseName, databaseVersion , databaseDisplayName, databaseSize);

//Using SQLite plugin
 myDB = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name : databaseName});
 }
```

and here on Button click Event i am trying to perform Operation with respective function name..

Create Table

```
function CreateMobileTable() {
    myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('CREATE ' +
                   'TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' +
                   'Mobile_Table (device_PhoneNumber integer)', [],
            function(tx, result) {
                alert("Mobile_Table  created successfully.");
            }, 
            function(error) {
                  alert("Error occurred while creating the table.");
            });
        });
      }
```

Insert Data.

```
 function InsertMobileData(){
        myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
            // Define insert query
            var executeQuery = "INSERT INTO " +
                                "Mobile_Table" + 
                                "(device_PhoneNumber) "+
                                "VALUES(?)";
            Helper.log(executeQuery);              
            transaction.executeSql(executeQuery, ['+callingNo+']
                , function(tx, result) {   // On success
                 alert("Mobile Number Inserted Successfully");
                },
                function(error){     // On error                               
                     alert("Error while inserting data");
                });
        });
}        
});
```

and Read Table data

```
function GetMobileNumber() {
myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql("SELECT device_PhoneNumber FROM Mobile_Table                                                   WHERE business_id =?", ['1234'],
    function(tx, result) {
          var dataLength = result.rows.length;
           console.log(dataLength);
          if(dataLength  > 0){
               var no = result.rows.item(0).business_name;
             alert(no);
           }else{
               alert("No Result Found");
           }
      }, 
      function(error) {
          alert("Error while fetching the data");
      });
  }); 
  }
```

The issue is that i am ot able to create the database nither getting nay alert message ..Also Other Features of my app are also not working ...
Please help me..Thanks..

Comment: `myDB` is a `local variable` inside the `onDeviceReady()`. It is not visible to other functions. You need to define it as a global variable, for that you need to define the `myDB` variable without the `var` keyword. i.e `myDB = "";`. This will make it available to other functions.

Comment: @frank As adviced my You i updated the code to `myDB = "";` and kept it at same place i.e inside `onDeviceReady()` but the issue continues .Any guesses Why ?

Comment: why are you using both `window.openDatabase` and `window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase`. You should be using either one of them. Maybe that is causing the issue. Also you need to wait for `DeviceReady()` **to complete** before performing any DB related tasks.

Comment: @frank Which one i should remove either first one or second.How can i get to know that device is ready ?

Comment: you can remove any one of them. It does not matter. Though if you  use `window.openDatabase` it will use the inbuilt WebSQL. If you want to make use of the plugin than you need to use  `window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase`.

Comment: Put an `alert()` **inside** the `onDeviceReady()` at the **end**. This will help you to know that the function has completed its execution. Also use a large database size i.e *25* is too small, at least 10000

Comment: @frank Thanks for your kind suggestion ..Now i am able to create the database and table but i am still not able to insert and read database..In Inserting i am not getting any alert message while in reading i am getting error alert message ..Why sir ?

Comment: @frank Am i doing something wrong in inserting and fetching data ..Please help me sir ?

Comment: @frank Please sir help me to point where am i going wrong ..?

Comment: @frank Is there any Mistake in my insertion code sir ..I am not able to get any alert message while inserting so getting Error alert while fetching ..Please help me sir ..Thanks